# "The requested URL was not found on the server" error while i was trying to use flask to deploy my Dl model

Tags: python, html, flask, deep-learning, server-side-rendering

Question: How can I resolve issues with my Flask application for sentiment analysis using the DistilBERT model? I am facing problems with the frontend not rendering correctly, getting "Not Found" errors, and difficulties handling POST and GET requests.

When accessing the root URL or the /classify endpoint, I receive a "Not Found" error, indicating that the requested URL is not found on the server. How can I troubleshoot this issue and ensure the URLs are correctly mapped to the Flask routes?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to help me resolve these issues and get my Flask application for sentiment analysis up and running smoothly. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Heres the flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english"
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sentiment_analysis():
    print('working')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.form['user_input']
        raw_string = user_input.strip()

        # Tokenize the input
        tf_batch = tokenizer(
            [raw_string],
            padding=True,
            truncation=True,
            max_length=512,
            return_tensors="tf"
        )

        # Get model predictions
        tf_outputs = model(tf_batch)
        tf_predictions = tf.nn.softmax(tf_outputs.logits, axis=-1)

        # Determine sentiment tags
        sentiment_tags = []
        for prediction in tf_predictions:
            if prediction[0] > prediction[1]:
                sentiment_tags.append("Negative")
            else:
                sentiment_tags.append("Positive")

        sentiment = sentiment_tags[0]
        return render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input, sentiment=sentiment)
    
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

and Here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Sentiment Analysis</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Text Sentiment Analysis</h1>

    <form class="p-3 text-center" action="/classify" method="post">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_input" placeholder="Enter the text to analyze">
        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="Analyze">
    </form>

    {% if sentiment %}
        <p class="text-center">Sentiment: {{ sentiment }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

1. Tried using the upgraded libraries using  pip installs , no luck
2. checked the folder and files position for the template folder and index.html file and ran it again ... no luck.

Comment: With the `action` attribute of the form you refer to a route `/classify` which does not exist within your code. Maybe you mean `/`.

Comment: Thank you @Detlef , You suggestion helped to run my code without any errors , Thanks man!